# ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver on OS X Yosemite

Tags: jdbc, derby, osx-yosemite, javadb

I use the version of Java 7 that comes with OS X Yosemite. My understanding is that Oracle by now ships Java DB (i.e. Derby) with Java, so perhaps I have it already installed.

I currently get a `ClassNotFoundException` when attempting `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")`.

Am I supposed to somehow add the driver from a local directory, or do I have to get it extra (e.g. because OS X comes with a JRE but not JDK)?

If the second is true, where should I get it from (i.e. are there any differences between drivers from Apache and Oracle)?

Comment: Derby isn't included in Java, you need to add it to your classpath yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am a bit confused because [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/javadb-156712.html) it says "Java DB is included in the JDK".

Comment: It is installed together with the JDK (at least with Java 7, not sure if they still do with Java 8), but it is not included in Java, so you still need to include it in the classpath yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah, so it's a JRE vs. JDK issue then. I'll try to get it from Apache then.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Obtaining the driver from Apache Derby 10.11.1.1 (in `derby.war`) apparently did the trick. If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Derby (or JavaDB) is installed together with the JDK (at least with Java 7, not sure if they still do with Java 8), it is not part of Java itself. This means you still need to include it in the classpath yourself.